# Have a function that compiles inline?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure that "inline function" is the correct terminology but here's what I am trying to achieve:

I sometimes have `WHERE` conditions in a query where a number of `AND`s and `OR`s are combined to the get the desired result from the database.

In good Uncle Bob fashion I would prefer to group these sub clauses into named functions so that in six months from now I still understand what I was trying to achieve, especially if the clause needs to be adapted.

If this were plain LINQ-to-objects this would not pose a problem but with the expression tree of `IQueryable` it can't translate the functions into SQL.

[There was a complex answer from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26744093/2334520) but I was wondering if something had changed in the years that would make it possible.

Taking the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54529163/2334520) into account I tried to convert:

```
string endField = "...";
query = query.Where(p => p.GS1.Any(
    g => g.Header == Decoder.DateAndTimeOfProductionIdentifier
         && string.Compare(g.Content, endField) <= 0));
```

However, I don't understand how I would get the `endField` parameter into this expression:

```
string endField = "...";
query = query.Where(Test());

private System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Packaging, bool>> Test()
{
    return p => p.GS1.Any(
        g => g.Header == Decoder.DateAndTimeOfProductionIdentifier
             && string.Compare(g.Content, endField) <= 0); //endField not defined here
}
```

Simply adding the string to the `expression function` doesn't work because then it won't match the signature that the `.Where` function is epecting.

Comment: Can you give an example? We have created extension methods on `IQueryable<T>` successfully without any hiccups. Maybe yours are more complicated, but I'd be suprised if it wouldn't work if the query as-is works.

Comment: ^^ Example doesn't have to be actually from your code (if you cannot disclose). Just a [mcve].

Comment: You say you're using LINQ to SQL but you have tagged the question EF Core. Which is it? The two are mutually exclusive. The LINQ provider for EF is LINQ to Enties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core - Use Extension Methods Inside Queryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512134/entity-framework-core-use-extension-methods-inside-queryable)

Comment: Check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120616/10646316) It shows how to use LINQKit for such purpose.

Comment: @Fildor Example given :-)

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, about the unclear terminology. I hope the added example will make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a simple example on what I am using and based on it you can enhance it further:

```
  private Expression<Func<Tdb, bool>> BuildConditionForProperty(string propertyName, int conditionValue)
    {
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tdb));
        var constant = Expression.Constant(conditionValue);
        var property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);
        var condition = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Tdb, bool>>(condition, parameterExpression);
    }//BuildConditionForProperty
```

This function (`BuildConditionForProperty`) build is used for a simple comparison between a column value from db and a specific value. Starting from here you can add more `Expression.Equal` or `Expression.Or` to create your conditional expression.

I am using it like this.

```
 var condition = BuildConditionForProperty("Id", (int)typeof(Tdto).GetProperty("Id").GetValue(data));
 var records = await _persistenceService.FindByCondition(lambdaCondition);
```

I hope this is answer that you are looking for.